# X64 installer using Won64 node registry

Tags: windows-installer, 64-bit, wow64, installshield-2008

I am using InstallShield 2008 premium edition. I created one basicMSI project only to target x64 platforms. I changed summary property to "x64".

But this installer is writing registry entries in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\CompanyName\ProductName" .

I am using both installshield script and vc++ DLL for custom actions.

Why x64 installer is using WOW64 registry ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the component property to 64-bit as well. You need both the template summary SIS property as well as the component setting, as a 64-bit installer can install to 32-bit locations.

Note that if you are writing to the registry from custom actions instead of the registry table, that will depend on the bitness of your code, as well as flags you pass to the registry functions. InstallScript is 32-bit all the time, and C++ will depend on how you compile it.